# Use of List Monad vs fmap

Tags: haskell, monads

Are there any practical uses of the list monad that wouldn't just roll to a fmap? When would you use bind over fmap with the list monad?

Like, for example, you can do `[1,2,3] >>= return . ( + 1)` but that's the same as `(+1) <$> [1,2,3]` - when would you use bind without a return on list?

Comment: `fmap` requires the result to have exactly as many elements as the original list; the monad lets you remove from (via `guard`) or add to (I assume; blanking on how) the resulting list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using bind with return is equivalent to using fmap. Indeed,

```
fmap f m = m >>= return . f
```

The uses of bind that can't be reproduced with fmap are exactly those which don't involve this use of return. To provide just one (hopefully) interesting example for lists, let's talk about [L-Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system).

L-systems were created by Aristid Lindenmeyer in 1968. As rewriting systems, they start with a simple object and repeatedly replace parts of it using a set of *rewriting rules* or *productions*. They can be used to generate fractals and other self-similar images. A context-free, deterministic L-System (or D0L) is defined by the triple of an alphabet, an axiom, and a collection of production rules.

For our alphabet, we'll define a type:

```
data AB = A | B deriving Show
```

for our axiom, or starting state, we'll use the word `[A, B]`.

```
myAxiom = [A, B]
```

For our rules, we need a map from a single letter to a sequence of letters. This is a function of type `AB -> [AB]`. Let's use this rule:

```
myRule :: AB -> [AB]
myRule A = [A, B]
myRule B = [A]
```

To apply the rule, we must rewrite each letter using its production rule. We must do this for all letters in the word at the same time. Conveniently, this is exactly what `>>=` does for lists:

```
apply rule axiom = axiom >>= rule
```

Now, let's apply our rule to our axiom, generating the first step in the L-System:

```
> apply myRule myAxiom
> [A, B, A]
```

This is Lindenmeyer's [original L-System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system#Example_1:_Algae), used for modeling algae. We can iterate to see it progress:

```
> mapM_ print . take 7 $ iterate (>>= myRule) myAxiom
[A,B]
[A,B,A]
[A,B,A,A,B]
[A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A]
[A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B]
[A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A]
[A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B]
```

In general, bind for lists is `concatMap`, and you use it precisely when you want to combine mapping with concatenation. Another interpretation is that lists represent non-deterministic choice and that bind functions by choosing each possibility from the list once. For example, rolling dice:

```
do
  d1 <- [1..6]
  d2 <- [1..6]
  return (d1, d2)
```

This gives all possible ways of rolling 2d6.

Answer (score 1):

```
factors :: Int -> [Int]
factors n = do
    q <- [1..n]
    filter ((==n) . (*q)) [1..n]
```

...or, in desugared notation,

```
factors n = [1..n] >>= ($[1..n]) . filter . fmap (==n) . (*)
```

That's of course hardly efficient, but it works:

```
*Main> factors 17
[17,1]
*Main> factors 24
[24,12,8,6,4,3,2,1]
*Main> factors 34
[34,17,2,1]
```

For operations that's aren't so simple as `*`, so you couldn't avoid a brute-force approach like that, this might actually be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, `concatMap` is just `(=<<)`. And `concat` is just `join`. I've used both of these frequently in real code.

Another thing you can do is apply a list of functions to one value.

```
λ:> applyList = sequence
λ:> applyList [(2*), (3+)] 4
[8,7]
```

You can also generate a list of all subsets of a list

```
λ:> import Control.Monad
λ:> allSubsets = filterM (const [True, False])
λ:> allSubsets "ego"
["ego","eg","eo","e","go","g","o",""]
```

Or even enumerate all strings that can be formed from an alphabet

```
λ:> import Data.List
λ:> import Control.Monad
λ:> allStrings = sequence <=< (inits . repeat)
λ:> take 100 $ allStrings ['a'..'z']
["","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","aa","ab","ac","ad","ae","af","ag","ah","ai","aj","ak","al","am","an","ao","ap","aq","ar","as","at","au","av","aw","ax","ay","az","ba","bb","bc","bd","be","bf","bg","bh","bi","bj","bk","bl","bm","bn","bo","bp","bq","br","bs","bt","bu","bv","bw","bx","by","bz","ca","cb","cc","cd","ce","cf","cg","ch","ci","cj","ck","cl","cm","cn","co","cp","cq","cr","cs","ct","cu"]
```

Perhaps more practically, you can use the applicative instance to combine two lists together

```
λ:> zipWith' f xs ys = f <$> xs <*> ys
λ:> zipWith' (+) [1..3] [5..8]
[6,7,8,9,7,8,9,10,8,9,10,11]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have much to do with "zippers" as the term is usually understood.

Comment: That `zipWith'` is not what it claims to be.  Maybe you are looking for the [`ZipList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) applicative?